# spaces from database shows wrong in HTML

Tags: php, mysql

when i get data from database, if string contains space, in html it shows as question mark in romb. i guess font don't have these 2 symbols-

if i do- `set names 'utf8'`, i still get wrong results-> like in Jaded Joys, there is an "A " not just space.

with phpmyadmin tables look good, there is space, not symbols.
any solution how to decode, replace those with space?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have everything set to utf8 including the content-type header, and the table?

Comment: yes, everything is in utf8

Answer (score 0):

i found solution.

```
$text = preg_replace("/[^\x20-\x7f\t\n\r]+/", " ", $text); // ascii only
```

run this over all rows, it replaced "bad" spaces, with regular ones.